# TableViewCell to auto-resize its height according to content in xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I need to set the height of `tableViewCell` according to content in it. I have some labels of dynamic height in `tableViewCell`,number of lines in the label is not constant. Sometimes if a one label's text is `null` then the other label may occupy its position. So what i need is `tableViewCell` should `autoresize` height according to the content?

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
self.tableView=[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,150,327,[array count]*205) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
                self.tableView.delegate=self;
                self.tableView.dataSource=self;
                self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
                [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];

                float fscrview = 150 + self.tableView.frame.size.height + 20;
                testscroll.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, fscrview);
}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

        return [array count];
    }

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"Cell";

        UITableViewCell* cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if(cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault    reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];


            UILabel *name1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
            name1.tag = 111;
            name1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            [name1 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14]];
            [name1 setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
            [cell addSubview:name1];

            UILabel *code = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
            codetype.tag = 112;
            codetype.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            [codetype setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]];
            [codetype setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
            [cell addSubview:codetype];

            line1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
            line1.tag = 113;
            line1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            [line1 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]];
            [line1 setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
            [cell addSubview:line1];


            line3 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
            line3.tag = 114;
            line3.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            [line3 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]];
            [line3 setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
            [cell addSubview:line3];

            city = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
            city.tag = 115;
            city.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            [city setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]];
            [city setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
            [cell addSubview:city];



        }

        cell.accessoryType= UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
        NSMutableDictionary *d =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary: [arr2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];


        NSString *name2 = [d  objectForKey:@"Name"];
        CGSize constraint1 = CGSizeMake(175, 2000.0f);
        CGSize size1 = [name2 sizeWithFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14] constrainedToSize:constraint1 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
        UILabel *name1 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:111];
        name1.frame = CGRectMake(105,25, 175, size1.height);
        [name1 setNumberOfLines:size1.height/16];
        name1.text = [d  objectForKey:@"Name"];
        [name1 setTextColor:UIColorFromRGB(COLOR_BLUE)];


        NSString *codetype2 = [d  objectForKey:@"Type"];
        CGSize constraint2 = CGSizeMake(175, 2000.0f);
        CGSize size2 = [codetype2 sizeWithFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:12] constrainedToSize:constraint2 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
        UILabel *codetype1 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:112];
        codetype1.frame = CGRectMake(105,name1.frame.size.height+25, 175, size2.height);
        [codetype1 setNumberOfLines:size2.height/16];
        codetype1.text=[d objectForKey:@"CodeType"];

        NSString *line2 = [d  objectForKey:@"Line1"];
        NSString *line4 = [d  objectForKey:@"Line2"];

        if([line2 isEqualToString:@""])
        {
            if([line4 isEqualToString:@""])
            {
                NSString *city2 = [d  objectForKey:@"City"];
                CGSize constraint4 = CGSizeMake(175, 2000.0f);
                CGSize size4 = [city2 sizeWithFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:12] constrainedToSize:constraint4 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
               city = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:115];
                city.frame = CGRectMake(105,codetype1.frame.size.height+codetype1.frame.origin.y, 175, size4.height);
                [city setNumberOfLines:0];
                city.text = [d  objectForKey:@"City"];
            }
            else
            {
                NSString *line4 = [d  objectForKey:@"Line2"];

                CGSize constraint4 = CGSizeMake(175, 2000.0f);
                CGSize size4 = [line4 sizeWithFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:12] constrainedToSize:constraint4 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
                line3 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:114];
                line3.frame = CGRectMake(105,codetype1.frame.size.height+codetype1.frame.origin.y, 175, size4.height);
                [line3 setNumberOfLines:0];
                line3.text = [d  objectForKey:@"Line2"];


                NSString *city2 = [d  objectForKey:@"City"];
                CGSize constraint5 = CGSizeMake(175, 2000.0f);
                CGSize size5 = [city2 sizeWithFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:12] constrainedToSize:constraint5 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
                city = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:115];
                city.frame = CGRectMake(105,line3.frame.size.height+line3.frame.origin.y, 175, size5.height);
                [city setNumberOfLines:0];
                city.text = [d  objectForKey:@"City"];





            }


        }
        else
        {
            NSString *line2 = [d  objectForKey:@"Line1"];
            CGSize constraint3 = CGSizeMake(175, 2000.0f);
            CGSize size3 = [line2 sizeWithFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:12] constrainedToSize:constraint3 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
            line1 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:113];
            line1.frame = CGRectMake(105,codetype1.frame.size.height+codetype1.frame.origin.y, 175, size3.height);
            [line1 setNumberOfLines:0];
            line1.text = [d  objectForKey:@"Line1"];

            if([line4 isEqualToString:@""])
            {
                NSString *city2 = [d  objectForKey:@"City"];
                CGSize constraint5 = CGSizeMake(175, 2000.0f);
                CGSize size5 = [city2 sizeWithFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:12] constrainedToSize:constraint5 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
               city = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:115];
                city.frame = CGRectMake(105,line1.frame.size.height+line1.frame.origin.y, 175, size5.height);
                [city setNumberOfLines:0];
                city.text = [d  objectForKey:@"City"];
            }
            else
            {
                NSString *line4 = [d  objectForKey:@"Line2"];

                CGSize constraint4 = CGSizeMake(175, 2000.0f);
                CGSize size4 = [line4 sizeWithFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:12] constrainedToSize:constraint4 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
                line3 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:114];
                line3.frame = CGRectMake(105,line1.frame.size.height+line1.frame.origin.y, 175, size4.height-3);
                [line3 setNumberOfLines:0];
                line3.text = [d  objectForKey:@"Line2"];



                NSString *city2 = [d  objectForKey:@"City"];
                CGSize constraint5 = CGSizeMake(175, 2000.0f);
                CGSize size5 = [city2 sizeWithFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:12] constrainedToSize:constraint5 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
                city = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:115];
                city.frame = CGRectMake(105,line3.frame.size.height+line3.frame.origin.y+4, 175, size5.height);
                [city setNumberOfLines:0];
                city.text = [d  objectForKey:@"City"];



            }



        }



        UILabel *state=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(105,city.frame.size.height+city.frame.origin.y+5,320,10)];
        state.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];
        [state setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
        [state setText:[d valueForKey:@"State"]];
        state.tag=116;
        [cell addSubview:state];
        [state release];

}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

        return 1;


}   
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
 UIView *sectionHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, tableView.sectionHeaderHeight)];
    sectionHeaderView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0];
    sectionHeaderView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    sectionHeaderView.tag = section;


    UILabel *headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12,2, tableView.bounds.size.width-10, 18)];
    headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [headerLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
    headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    headerLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    headerLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
    headerLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];
    headerLabel.text = @"Details";


    [sectionHeaderView addSubview:headerLabel];

    return sectionHeaderView;
    }
```

Here i have given it to be 205 .but when the text in the `tableViewCell` increases then i couldn't see the last lines of the label of last `tableViewCell`..

How can i make `tableViewCell` to `auto-resize` its height ?

Comment: post your table view delegate methods code too

Comment: I have edited it.Can u please have a look and let me know where to modify?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the height of a cell in `– tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGFloat height=60;  //set default row height
    if(check_for_the_rows_which_need_increased_height) {
        height+=50;   //Add appropriate increase
    }
    return height;
}
```

You need to call `[yourTableView reloadData]` or `[yourTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPath withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic]` for above method to be called again.

Comment: Can I know what is this? index_of_row_which_needs_increased_height

Comment: I have updated answer. Replace check_for_the_rows_which_need_increased_height with your condition to check which rows should have increased height

Comment: But I dont know which row need_increased_height bcoz all the rows and the data inside it changes at runtime..So what should I give there?check_for_the_rows_which_need_increased_height?

Comment: But if i don't wish to regenerate the view as it contains a lot of data

Answer (score 1):

You can just check for you textHeight and then set your row height

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
  NSString *Yourtext = [yourTextAry objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

  CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(yourLabelWidth , 20000.0f);

  CGSize size = [Yourtext sizeWithFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:13] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

  CGFloat height = MAX(size.height, 44.0f);

  return height;
}
```

and if text is null then remove it from array dear or just pass height to zero..:)

Comment: hey sorry for the delay..can u edit it for 3 labels with the second label empty(no text) and what is 44.0f in MAX(size.height, 44.0f)?

Comment: 44 is default size of table row... and for 3 label you just apply your logic... (firstLavelSize.height + secondLabel.height(empty so just take its frame height) + 3rdLabelSize.height)

Comment: I couldn't get it. Im confused.see if we have declared to take max height then what is the need of height in creating the UIlables in cellForRowAtIndexPath?And while creating the tableview what do we give the height of tableview ?

Comment: brother if you have one label with small text then it will reduce your row height if you don't use 44

Comment: then what is the need of height in creating the UIlables in cellForRowAtIndexPath?And while creating the tableview what do we give the height of tableview ?

Comment: in this heightForRowAtIndexPath we are getting only height of row, and in cellForRowAtIndexPath we are creating label to display label in row...