# how to adjust the height of a cell when loading from the custom tableview cell classes?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview, custom-cell

I have an application in which i am adding 2 types of cells in two designs. So I am using custom `UITableViewCell` object classes. But my problem is I am using a text view in this cells. I need to adjust the row height according to its content size. This is what my code looks like:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"CellIdentifier";
    static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"Cell";
        
    if(messagesarray==nil||[messagesarray count]==0)
    {
        
    }
    else
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *dicttable=[messagesarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSString *head=[dicttable objectForKey:@"gfgfg"];
        NSString *head1=[dicttable objectForKey:@"gfgfgf"];
        if([type isEqualToString:@"m"])    
        {
            if([head isEqualToString:@"NA"])
            {
             
                CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];
                if (cell == nil)
                {
                    cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier1] autorelease];
                    cell.backgroundView = [ [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"white_top_portion.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ]autorelease];
                }
                cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
                cell.nameLabel.text=head;
                cell.msg.text=head1;
                [cell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(callAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];     
              
                if(icon!=nil)
                {
                    if(![[ImageCache sharedImageCache] hasImageWithKey:icon])
                    {
                        cell.myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fggtgf.png"];
                        NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:cell.myImageView,icon,@"fgfgfg.png",[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],nil];
                        AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate  *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
                        [appDelegate performSelectorInBackground:@selector(updateImageViewInBackground:) withObject:myArray];   
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        cell.myImageView.image = [[ImageCache sharedImageCache] getImagefromCacheOrUrl:icon];
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    cell.myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fgfgfg.png"];  
                  
                } 
         
                cell.label.text=sub;   
                return cell;
            }
            else
            {
                Customcellwithimage *cell = (Customcellwithimage *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
             
                if (cell == nil)
                {
                    cell = [[[Customcellwithimage alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier2] autorelease];
                    cell.backgroundView = [ [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"white_deal_bg.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ]autorelease];
                }
             
                cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
                cell.datelabel1.text=subtitle;
                cell.nameLabel1.text=head;
                cell.msg1.text=head1;
                if(icon!=nil)
                {
                    if(![[ImageCache sharedImageCache] hasImageWithKey:icon])
                    {
                        cell.myImageView1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fgfgfgf.png"];
                        NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:cell.myImageView1,icon,@"fgfgfgf.png",[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],nil];
                        MFAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MFAppDelegate  *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
                        [appDelegate performSelectorInBackground:@selector(updateImageViewInBackground:) withObject:myArray];   
                       
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        cell.myImageView1.image = [[ImageCache sharedImageCache] getImagefromCacheOrUrl:icon];
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    cell.myImageView1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fgfgfgf.png"];  
                } 
              
                cell.cellview1.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"vf.png"];
                cell.label1.text=sub;
                [cell.button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(callAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
                cell.bannerview1.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"vfgf.png"];
                return cell;
            }   
        }                 
    }  
}
```

can anybody help me in achieving the row height as different for different cells?.I have to find out the height in `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`and i tried a method will  need to find out the cell object of the current row.but didnt succeed .can anybody guide me in right direction

Comment: Can you post your implementation of `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)` - not sure what the problem is.

Comment: check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656857/tableviewcell-to-auto-resize-its-height-according-to-content-in-xcode/13658437#13658437

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` - Here you can calculate the height for each individual row.

*Note*, if the calculation is a lot of work, you might see a reduction in performance. If this is the case you can pre-calculate the values and store them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method for variable height support for your application.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Whenever you want to set the height dynamically, call this method with your tableview object.

For more info [Click Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

or use this method with other tableview delegate methods.

Comment: sorry..that i know. ineed a way in this particular case inside this methode

Comment: i have written this above.. Well You can use this line where you want to change row height:     [tableView setRowHeight:<desired value in float>];

Answer (score 0):

Cell resizing can get pretty complicated, especially when UITextViews are involved. I suggest you simply use a table view framework such as *Sensible TableView*, where all the cells are automatically resized to fit contents. I believe they also now have a free version.